# Ruby: delete columns by name in MS Excel on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, excel

Is there a way to use Ruby to delete columns in an Excel spreadsheet by name (i.e. the value in the first row of the spreadsheet) on a Windows machine?

Background if you want it:
I am going to be receiving a large number of Excel spreadsheets on a regular basis.  Some of these spreadsheets will contain columns that need to be deleted.  I will know the names (first-row values) of the columns, but their positions in their respective spreadsheets will change from time to time, so I won't be able to automatically refer to the columns by letter.  I would really like to be able to automate this process...

Comment: Which Excel version are you talking about?

Comment: Either 97-2003 or 2007 would be fine-- sorry I didn't specify-

Answer (score 0):

POI is the Apache project to create a library for reading MS Office files; it appears they have Ruby extensions. I have never used it before, but the code looks easy enough to understand. Good luck! [Check it out here](http://poi.apache.org/poi-ruby.html)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the WIN32OLE library, built into the standard library on Windows. There's an example in [PickAxe](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/win32.html) about using Microsoft Excel through the WIN32OLE library, and [other examples here](http://www.devdaily.com/scw/ruby/win32ole/sample/). You just need to learn how to use the Excel COM API to make the particular changes you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you-- I did know about those examples, but I just don't know how to translate column "names" into Excel's coordinates.  Do you know how I would go about learning how to use the Excel COM API?

Comment: I don't really know. The COM API is the same API that's used for writing Excel macros, so I think you could use the object browser in the macro editor, and there may be help files on it also.